# Which dependency is my duplicate Slf4j binding coming from in this maven dependency tree?

Tags: java, spring, maven, kotlin, slf4j

I have been slamming my head against my desk for the past week trying to interpret this warning.

I am getting the following notification in my run output when trying to run my multi-module Spring/Kotlin/Maven application:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/vboxuser/Scratch/demo-server/controller/target/controller-0.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/vboxuser/Scratch/demo-server/controller/target/controller-0.1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.2.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

Here we see there are two bindings coming from my controller module, but i'm having troubles determining where they are both coming from.

My project is structured like the following with 3 total pom files:

```
parent
 |--controller
 |--utilities
```

Here is my maven dependency tree for the controller module:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.3.0:tree (default-cli) @ controller ---
[INFO] app.demo.server.controller:controller:jar:0.1.0
[INFO] +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.7.21:compile - version managed from 1.7.21; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:jar:1.7.21:compile (version managed from 1.7.21)
[INFO] |     \- (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.7.21:compile - version managed from 1.7.21; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:jar:1.7.21:compile (version managed from 1.7.21)
[INFO] |  \- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:13.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.7.21:compile - version managed from 1.7.21; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.7.7:compile (version managed from 2.7.7)
[INFO]    |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.24:compile - version managed from 5.3.24; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.24:compile (version managed from 5.3.24)
[INFO]    |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.24:compile (version managed from 5.3.24)
[INFO]    |     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.24:compile - version managed from 5.3.24; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.24:compile - version managed from 5.3.24; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.24:compile (version managed from 5.3.24)
[INFO]    |     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.24:compile - version managed from 5.3.24; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |     +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.24:compile - version managed from 5.3.24; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.24:compile (version managed from 5.3.24)
[INFO]    |        \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.24:compile - version managed from 5.3.24; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.7.7:compile (version managed from 2.7.7)
[INFO]    |  \- (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.7.7:compile - version managed from 2.7.7; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.7.7:compile (version managed from 2.7.7)
[INFO]    |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.11:compile (version managed from 1.2.11)
[INFO]    |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.11:compile (version managed from 1.2.11)
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile (version managed from 1.7.32)
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.2:compile (version managed from 2.17.2)
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile - version managed from 1.7.35; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.2:compile (version managed from 2.17.2)
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.osgi:org.osgi.core:jar:4.3.1:provided
[INFO]    |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:compile (version managed from 1.7.36)
[INFO]    |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile - version managed from 1.7.36; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile (version managed from 1.3.5)
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.24:compile (version managed from 5.3.24)
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.24:compile (version managed from 5.3.24)
[INFO]    \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.33:compile (version managed from 1.30)
```

Specifically, you might notice that slf4j is coming from the `spring-boot-starter-logging` dependency from `spring-boot-starter`

Taking a closer look at the spring boot logging dependency, i'm still not entirely sure where my issue is coming from. i see there are three dependencies here with slf4j, but they don't appear to be duplicates:

```
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.7.7:compile (version managed from 2.7.7)
[INFO]    |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.11:compile (version managed from 1.2.11)
[INFO]    |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.11:compile (version managed from 1.2.11)
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile (version managed from 1.7.32)
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.2:compile (version managed from 2.17.2)
[INFO]    |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile - version managed from 1.7.35; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.2:compile (version managed from 2.17.2)
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.osgi:org.osgi.core:jar:4.3.1:provided
[INFO]    |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:compile (version managed from 1.7.36)
[INFO]    |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile - version managed from 1.7.36; omitted for duplicate)
```

So what's the issue here? I'm having troubles finding anyone with a similar issue, where most folks are seeing multiple occurrences of slf4j in their dependency tree, though i seem to be struggling to either 1. see where the duplicate is coming from or 2. have a separate issue going on here.

Here is the pom file that's giving me issues:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>app.demo.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo-server</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>app.demo.server.controller</groupId>
    <artifactId>controller</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- main module kotlin required plugins begin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--main module kotlin required plugins end-->
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <main.class>app.demo.server.driver.demoController</main.class>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Here is the parent pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>app.demo.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-server</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>controller</module>
        <module>utilities</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>${java.jvm.version}</jvmTarget>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.jvm.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.jvm.version}</target>
                    <release>${java.jvm.version}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals> <goal>single</goal> </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <revision>0.1.0</revision>
        <kotlin.version>1.7.21</kotlin.version>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <java.jvm.version>11</java.jvm.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.3.0</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <maven-assembly-plugin.version>3.4.2</maven-assembly-plugin.version>
        <spring.version>2.7.7</spring.version>
        <snakeyaml.version>1.33</snakeyaml.version>
        <kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>11</kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>
        <logback-classic.version>1.4.5</logback-classic.version>
        <logback-core.version>1.4.5</logback-core.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I am compiling by running `mvn clean install` then running `java -jar controller/target/controller-${version}.jar`.

I am using kotlin version 7.21 java 11 and mvn 3.6.3

Comment: It appears to me that one of the two versions of the `StaticLoggerBinder` class is defined in your own source code rather than in a dependency jar file.  Note that the first reference at the top of your question shows something in the `classes` dir rather than the `lib` dir, and the first one does not include a jar file name.  Might you have a copy of the slf4j source code lying around somewhere and that code is somehow being picked up and compiled by Maven?  If you're not sure, I'd suggest that you look for a `StaticLoggerBinder.jar` file on your system.

Comment: One of the class does not come from a dependency JAR but from your code or SpringBoot maybe does weird things.

Comment: @CryptoFool i can be pretty confident that i am not defining StaticLoggerBinder anywhere in my source code. As of right now the only thing this project can do is say hello world. the virtual machine i'm working on is pretty new so there's not all that much on the system, though a `find . -name StaticLoggerBinder.jar` from my home directory yields no results. for maven-assembly-plugin i am using jar-with-dependencies. could this be related?

Comment: The error indicates you have a compiled StaticLoggerBinder class in your classes directory. You should be able to verify this by checking the directory. Try deleting the class file and then mvn compile. If the class file reappears then something in your build is placing it there.

Comment: gotcha.  so I have no clue then.  As @GaëlJ says, maybe Maven is doing something weird.  One thing you might try is to unzip your jar file and check to see if that class file indeed exists on its own in the `classes` dir.  Maybe a look at what else is in there could give you a clue as to what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is clear what is going on:

`spring-boot-maven-plugin` typically does the following: it takes primary artifact (jar file), unpacks it and creates another jar file with "executable jar" structure. The problem is, in your case "primary artifact" gets overridden due to `maven-assembly-plugin` configuration coming from parent pom:

```xml
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals> <goal>single</goal> </goals>
      <configuration>
       <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
       </descriptorRefs>
       <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
```

So, instead of repackaging original jar file `spring-boot-maven-plugin` repackages result of `maven-assembly-plugin`, and thus you are getting duplicate classes in "classpath" (I believe the size of resulting jar is twice more than expected).

You have following options:

1. remove `maven-assembly-plugin` configuration from parent pom (or move it under `<pluginManagement>`)
2. do not override primary artifact but create supplemental ones, i.e. set `<appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>`
3. disable `maven-assembly-plugin` configuration in controller pom, via specifying `<goal>none</goal>` or `<skipAssembly>true</skipAssembly>` something like:

```xml
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals> <goal>none</goal> </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
```

or:

```xml
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals> <goal>single</goal> </goals>
      <configuration>
       <skipAssembly>true</skipAssembly>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
```